# if else statement returning undefined with redux state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a function that takes in an object called conversation. this conversation object has a unique participant id that I use to fetch a matching participant from my redux state. everything logs fine but when I go to set my contact if the conversation.conversationSid is true, it returns undefined. Am I missing something here? Am I declaring my variables incorrect?

```
const getContact =(conversation) => { 
    console.log(conversation) correctly logs the object 
    let contact = { };
    
   if (conversation?.conversationSid) { // if newSid isnt our defualt
    const psidMatch =  participants.find(({ sid }) =>  sid === conversation?.participantSid ); 
    
    const updatedNumber =  psidMatch?.number?.replace("+", " ")
    contact = contacts.find(({phone_number}) => phone_number === updatedNumber)
   } else {
  contact = { firstName: "kevin", lastName: "baker" }
  
  } 
    
    console.log(contact) // this is returning undefined if the if statement is true.. if false it logs fine. the main contacts array logs fine...
    return contact;
  };
```

contacts array

```
0: {group: Array(1), _id: '6173cae28a', phone_number: '17705555555', firstName: 'Chad', 
1: {group: Array(1), _id: '617b04b75b', phone_number: '18165055555',  firstName: 'Barskin', 
2: {group: Array(1), _id: '617b04d15b', phone_number: '13039555555', firstName: 'Broski',
```

updatedNumber if you console.log it right under the replace

```
 13039555555
```

Comment: What's the structure of `participants` & `conversation`?

Comment: I see you are replacing the  '+' with an empty space ' ', so after replacing your number will be ' 13039555555', that means it is never going to match the '13039555555', can you check this @amandaConda

Comment: Wow this is right, I though javascript would ignore the space... I went ahead and changed to const updatedNumber =  psidMatch?.number?.substr(1, psidMatch?.number?.length) and got what I wanted. THANK YOU RAVITEJA V YOUR PRETTY SMART